# Cannot access JSP webservice in remote which is deployed in local

Tags: eclipse, web-services, jsp, tomcat, axis

I have deployed a JSP web service using Eclipse - Axis service- Tomcat server in the local machine.

Its URL is http://192.168.1.14:8080/Power_Watch_service/services/PW_Web_Service?wsdl (192.168.1.14 is the address of the local host),

We could not access this service from another neighboring machine connected to same network. I would like this link to be accessible  from other machines (of the same network or remotely from internet).

Can you give us some idea regarding this ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the symptom of the problem when accessing from another host of the local network ?

If you get a message telling that the server is not accessible it might be a firewall restriction from the Tomcat machine. I.e : you need to open the port 8080 as it appears in the URL.

For the question of being accessible from the Internet, it is quite similar : you will need to expose the local machine to the outside. On a "little" network it may need a setting in your ISP modem and / or rooter (virtual host / port redirection), but for an enterprise network it might be more difficult to do (and often even a bad idea - ask you local admin ;)